# AMP page error "invalid tag error" @charset

Tags: google-search-console, amp

How can I resolve the @charset “invalid tag error” on my AMP page?

Here is the line of code on the page that is causing the issue:

```
<style amp-custom>
    @charset "UTF-8";
    (...more CSS...)
</style>
```

Answer (score 1):

According to MDN, `@charset`:

> cannot be used ... inside the `<style>` element where the character set of the HTML page is relevant.
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@charset

Since AMP pages are required to be UTF-8 encoded and they use meta tags to specify such, this falls under the case where the "character set of the HTML page is relevant".

**In short, AMP pages are not allowed to use `@charset` in a `style` tag.**

Remove the `@charset` declaration from inside if your `style` tag, and the error will go away.

You can use the [AMP Validator](https://validator.ampproject.org/) to help debug.

Comment: I don't know how to remove the @charset, where should I navigate to. I have checked all through my WordPress dashboard, the plugins directory and can't find the AMP HTML. Please someone should help

Comment: @EmmanuelTochukwuAloysius There's some plugin that's generating AMP. Scrutinize each plugin carefully.

Comment: Okay but how do I scrutinized these plugin

Comment: @EmmanuelTochukwuAloysius Google each of them and see whether they are related to AMP at all.